# How do I map keys not simultaniously in vim?

Tags: vim

I don't know if sequentially is the right word, but I'd like to `nnoremap` `Ctrl+t` to `Ctrl+y` and then a comma. Is that possible or do I need to do this another way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add

`nnoremap <C-t><C-y>, a`

to your ~/.vimrc, where `<C-t>` and `<C-y>` are `ctrl+t` and `ctrl+y`, respectively, and `a` is whatever action you want to have the keys map to.

Comment: I mean I want <C-t> to map to <C-y>+, but not simultaneously. I want it to press <C-y>, release it, and then press ,

Comment: Meaning you just want to map `<C-t>` to `<C-y>` and the comma is not part of the mapping? Like `nnoremap <C-t> <C-y>`? or you mean like `nnoremap <C-t> <C-y>,`? Either way, I think the answer is yes, unless I'm missing something you're asking for.

Comment: <C-y>, will press the keys Ctrl, y and comma at the same time. I want it to press Ctrl and y, then release them both and then press the comma key

Comment: What do you think `,` alone is supposed to do in normal mode? And what do you think `<C-y>` is supposed to do?

Comment: in the emmet-vim plugin, the autocomplete shortcut is ```<C-y>``` followed by ```,```

Comment: Oh so you don't want the non-recursive mapping. Try `nmap` instead of `nnoremap`. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You map *the keys you want to press* to *what you want to happen*.

- If you want `Ctrl+t` to happen when you press `Ctrl+y` then `,`, then your mapping should look like this:

  ```
  nnoremap <C-y>, <C-t>
  ```
- If you want `Ctrl+y` then `,` to happen when you press `Ctrl+t`, then your mapping should look like this:

  ```
  nnoremap <C-t> <C-y>,
  ```

The concept of mapping is introduced in chapter 40 of the user manual, which you *should* have read, and further discussed under `:help mapping`.

But, judging by your comments under the other answer, creating a normal mode non-recursive mapping is not the solution to your problem.

First, because the plugin exposes `<C-y>,` in normal, visual, select, and insert modes so you must cover all of them:

```
" insert mode
inoremap <C-t> <C-y>,
" visual mode and select mode
vnoremap <C-t> <C-y>,
" normal mode
nnoremap <C-t> <C-y>,
```

Second, because `<C-y>,` is itself a mapping so you want your custom mapping to be recursive:

```
imap <C-t> <C-y>,
vmap <C-t> <C-y>,
nmap <C-t> <C-y>,
```

While the mappings above work, the whole idea a bit shortsighted because:

- The `<C-y>` in `<C-y>,` is a "leader" that is common to all the mappings exposed by that plugin. You can now press `<C-t>` instead of `<C-y>,` but all the other functionalities of that plugin are still behind that `<C-y>` leader and still follow that `<leader><key>` pattern so your system is now inconsistent.
- You are overriding `<C-t>` in normal and insert modes, where it is pretty useful.